# How to use one of the variables to distinguish duplicated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

For example:
we have 3*2 duplicated rows as follows:

```
name   identity   gender
Mary   student    female 
Mary   student    female
Mary   student    female
Jack   teacher    male
Jack   teacher    male
Jack   teacher    male
```

I wanna make those 3 rows as follows:

```
name    identity   gender
Mary1   student    female 
Mary2   student    female
Mary3   student    female
Jack1   teacher    male
Jack2   teacher    male
Jack3   teacher    male
```

How could I do it? Thanks

I try to use create function tvValues, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
    case when count(*) over(partition by name, identity, gender) > 1
        then concat(name, row_number() over(partition by name, identity, gender order by name))
        else name
    end as new_name
from mytable t
```

This appends a sequential number to names that belong to a duplicate row.

We can turn the statement to an update with an updatable CTE :

```
with cte as (
    select name,
        count(*) over(partition by name, identity, gender) cnt,
        row_number() over(partition by name, identity, gender order by name) rn
    from mytable
)
update cte
set name = concat(name, rn)
where cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NAME, IDENTITY, GENDER)`

You can change your order by if those need tweaked with `ASC`/`DESC`.

So you’re SELECT could start:

```
SELECT CONCAT(NAME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NAME, IDENTITY, GENDER)), IDENTITY, GENDER FROM …
```